# Converting nested select into join

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is

```
select COUNT(*) from result 
where test_id in (select test_id 
                    from test_schedule 
                    where scheduler_id in (select user_id 
                                           from users 
                                           where user_type=1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM result r
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT test_id
      FROM test_schedule s
      JOIN users u ON s.scheduler_id = u.user_id
      WHERE u.user_type = 1) s
USING (test_id)
```

The DISTINCT is necessary to keep rows from being multiplied by all the rows in the other tables that match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(r.*)
FROM result r
INNER JOIN test_schedule s ON r.test_id = s.test_id
INNER JOIN users u ON s.scheduler_id  = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_type = 1
```

Comment: @shashank - The two syntax may be different in some cases for example if there are any `NULL` values of the `scheduler_id` or the `test_id` the where clause won't return any values.

Comment: This will return a larger result if there are multiple matching rows in `test_schedule` or `users`, since it will count all the matches separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(r.*)
FROM result r
RIGHT JOIN test_schedule s USING(test_id)
RIGHT JOIN users u ON s.scheduler_id  = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_type = 1
```

Comment: That's essentially the same as Mahmoud Gamal's answer, which he said returns the wrong result.

Comment: Same thing I am getting again.