# MySql convert nested SELECT IN queries into JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, sql-update

I read that using IN in MySql queries causes a slowdown in performance, unlike in Oracle and that a JOIN should be used instead. I am able to convert simple queries, but I am struggling with more complex ones that contain nested SELECTs. For example:

```
update Records set ActiveStatus=0, TransactionStatus=0, LastUpdated=& 
where ActiveStatus!=5 and LastUpdated!=& 
and Pk in (select RecordPk from GroupRecordLink 
where GroupPk in (select Pk from Groups where ActiveStatus!=5 and 
DateTimeStamp>&))
```

I had a go rewriting it by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134540/converting-nested-select-into-join) , but I am not sure my result is correct.

```
update Records r join (select distinct RecordPk from GroupRecordLink grl join 
Groups g on grl.Pk = g.Pk where g.ActiveStatus!=5 and g.DateTimeStamp>&) s
using (Pk) set ActiveStatus=0, TransactionStatus=0, LastUpdated=&  
where ActiveStatus!=5 and DateTimeStamp>&
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, compare the output of the 1st query with your attempt and if the results match, then you got it right. But I think you overcomplicated the attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Records 
INNER JOIN GroupRecordLink ON Records.Pk = GroupRecordLink.RecordPk 
INNER JOIN Groups ON GroupRecordLink.GroupPk = Groups.Pk AND Groups.ActiveStatus != 5 
SET Records.ActiveStatus = 0, 
    Records.TransactionStatus = 0, 
    Records.LastUpdated = & 
WHERE Records.ActiveStatus != 5 
  AND Records.LastUpdated != &;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql you could use an explicit join for update   (you must change & witha proper value )

```
    update Records 
    INNER JOIN GroupRecordLink on GroupRecordLink.RecordPk = Records.PK
    INNER JOIN Groups on ( GroupRecordLink.GroupPk = Groups.Pk 
                  and  Groups.ActiveStatus!=5
                         and Groups.DateTimeStamp>&)
    set ActiveStatus=0, 
    TransactionStatus=0, 
    LastUpdated=&
```